# Lay a damp proof membrane followed by a self levelling compound

Tags: concrete, self-leveling-concrete, damp-proof-course

I have an uneven concrete floor inside. I need to put down a damp proof membrane and self levelling compound on top of that. My questions are:

1. Is there any reason to use a roll of DPM vs a liquid one or vice versa?
2. Do I need to apply any sort of primer before putting down the SLC on top of the DPM?
3. How thick does my layer of SLC need to be? I've seen various people quote up to 65mm! I really don't want to lose that much height.

If it makes a difference, vinyl will be stuck down over the SLC.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recently put down Mapei Self Leveler Plus over a plywood subfloor.  It requires "Primer T" or "Eco Prim Grip" primer to be applied first and allowed to dry before applying the self-leveler.  I don't know anything about using damp-proof membranes.  I have a friend who has a concrete floor in her garage.  She has ground water under the garage that comes through the concrete.  If you have that problem, I don't think a damp-proof membrane on top of the concrete will help.

Comment: I would probably level and install the vinyl it will act as a moisture barrier. Unless there are water issues with the slab you did not address.